# 404 not being caught?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have been running some automated security scans and the following URL triggers a 404:

`/%FF%FE%3Cscript%3Ehaikumsg%28326%29%3C%2Fscript%3E`

This is run from the route on the domain on an Apache server (so this should be easy to replicate).

My htaccess is setup with `ErrorDocument 404 /site/404` but this isn't being caught. I know this because if I completely empty the htaccess file I am still presented with the same standard apache 404 page.

Clearly this is a  tag hack so I have to be careful how its handled, however I'd like to know how to manage it so it at least does my `/site/404` instead of nothing.

Comment: This is probably getting caught by some additional security module or firewall, so that it does not even get that far, that your custom configuration for the error document could even apply.

Comment: How could I check/investigate that?

Comment: Check the log files? Talk to your server admin?

Comment: Thanks (and don't know why I just didn't think of that!!) but that would be me! Log files don't report anything - no errors related to the 404.

Comment: Could be something like ModSecurity or similar.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the solution is to *move your 404 redirect to the Vhosts not htaccess*!! Very simple solution and that will fix it. Apache obviously works with the URL before even getting to the htaccess file so moving the 404 redirect is needed at a higher level.

However if you need to decode and use the URLs then the following begins to help:
https://serverfault.com/questions/261683/how-does-apache-process-a-path-with-a-percent-encoded-url-in-it

Basically the solution is to add `AllowEncodedSlashes On` to the Vhosts file.

As per https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes.

Comment: To clarify, the initial 404 (that is triggered early by Apache) is caused by the `%2F` (encoded slash) in the URL. A "security feature". This is regardless of whether or not the request would actually map to a valid resource.